# Permutation diagram in r

Tags: r, permutation, diagram, figure

I have a data.frame showing the strength of the relationship between all possible combination of the variables at site x with the variable at site y.

```
set.seed(1410)
df<-data.frame(
"site.x"=c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4),rep("c",4),rep("d",4)),
"site.y"=c(rep(c("e","f","g","h"),4)),
"bond.strength"=sample(1:100,16, replace=TRUE))

   site.x site.y bond.strength
    a      e            27
    a      f            54
    a      g            94
    a      h            15
    b      e            58
    b      f            50
    b      g            67
    b      h            51
    c      e            58
    c      f             5
    c      g            48
    c      h            32
    d      e             5
    d      f            13
    d      g            84
    d      h            39
```

I need a diagram that can summarise the information in df in one figure. I was thinking perhaps a permutation diagram like this.....

[image]

Any suggestions how I would go about something like this? Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives something similar using your data:

```
library(igraph)
df<-graph.data.frame(df)
V(df)$names <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
layOUT<-data.frame(x=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4)),y=c(4:1,4:1))
E(df)[ bond.strength < 101 ]$color <- "red"
E(df)[ bond.strength < 67 ]$color <- "yellow"
E(df)[ bond.strength < 34 ]$color <- "green"
V(df)$color <- "white"
l<-as.matrix(layOUT)
plot(df,layout=l,vertex.size=10,vertex.label=V(df)$names,
edge.arrow.size=0.01,vertex.label.color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am trying to use it as a model for my actual data. Could you please explain the layOUT step? I understand it has something to do with how the nodes are organised. How would I adjust it to say hand a case where site x had 10 items and site y only had 6? Thanks

Comment: Hey, the layOUT step just creates coordinates for the nodes. Once you have run the code type `layout` and hit enter.  You will see its just  data frame where the `x` column are node x-coordinates and the `y` column are node y-coordinates.  `igraph` uses these coordinates as a matrix so `as.matrix` just puts it in  format `igraph` can use.

Comment: everything wil still work even if there are differnt numbers of nodes.  The length of the `x` and `y` in my example is 8 because you have 8 nodes. For example if you had 16 nodes you could make `layOUT` with this `layOUT<-data.frame(x=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,6)),y=c(10:1,10:5))`

Comment: Got it to work, thanks. Sorry just one final question...how can I add a legend?

Comment: after you plot try something like this `legend("bottomright", col=c("green","yellow","red"), c("0-33","33-66","66-100"), pch=15)`. Look at `?legend` for tweeking this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way that uses base R, and should work for any data frame with the same structure. Note that I changed factors to strings in the original sample.

```
set.seed(1410)
df<-data.frame(
  "site.x"=c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4),rep("c",4),rep("d",4)),
  "site.y"=c(rep(c("e","f","g","h"),4)),
  "bond.strength"=sample(1:100,16, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


Placement <- data.frame(site=c(unique(df$site.x),unique(df$site.y)), x = NA, y = NA, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Placement$x <- ifelse(Placement$site %in% unique(df$site.x), 0, 1)

Placement$y[Placement$x==0] <- seq(1,0,length=sum(Placement$x==0))
Placement$y[Placement$x==1] <- seq(1,0,length=sum(Placement$x==1))

cols <- rep("red",nrow(df))
cols[df$bond.strength < 33] <- "green"
cols[df$bond.strength >= 33 & df$bond.strength < 66] <- "yellow"

# Empty plot:
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(1,type="n",xlim=c(-0.2,1.6),ylim=c(0,1),bty="n",axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
abline(v=c(0,1))
text(Placement$x + ifelse(Placement$x==0,-0.1,0.1),Placement$y,Placement$site)

for (i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  lines(c(0,1),Placement$y[c(match(df$site.x[i],Placement$site),match(df$site.y[i],Placement$site))],col=cols[i],lwd=2)
}

legend("right",col=c("green","yellow","red"),lty=1,lwd=2,legend=c("0-33","33-66","66-100"),title="bondstrength",cex=1.5,bty="n")
```

[image]